# How to make installer package with multiple executables in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-installer

I'm making a small backup app that comprises three parts.

1. A **system tray "config" utility** where the user specifies backup source / target locations, times they want the backup to run etc.
2. When changes are made, this calls **another exe which creates a scheduled task** for the backup. (It's a separate part because this part must be elevated.)
3. The third part is **the exe that performs the backup**. (It compresses and uploads by ftp to a server somewhere.) This is the exe that is run by the scheduled task.

How do I package these up (preferably in VS2013, if not using some freeware) so they are all installed together? (They each use a couple of (different) custom dlls. For example the backup component uses [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) and [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), and the scheduling component uses the Win32.TaskScheduler.)

I basically just want the user to run a single installer that will install all three exes and their dependencies.

These are currently three separate projects, with three different solutions. I can combine to one solution if it makes it simpler.

Comment: you can write a code that runs that 3 exes and ask the user to run only that code program.

Comment: Have you tried adding the extra exe's into the deploy folder manually? Using the setup config? You can add any extra files like this, but I am not sure it if will look for the dependencies of said files... it might be worth a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Louis Van mentioned in this comment You can add one of these executable as `primary output` to your installer project and the remaining two exes can be added to the installation bin directory using `Add > File..` option.

When you add an executable to Application Folder of your installer, References of relevant exe will be detected and automatically included by the windows installer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [free edition of Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html) (create "Simple" project) to package them up in a MSI. It also includes a [VS extension](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/ai-ext-vs.html), so you can have the MSI built right out of VS.